# Элементы коллекции через один в Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Хочу в новую коллекцию выбрать все элементы "через один":

```
Dictonary<string,double> dict 
dict.OrderByDescending(v => v.Value)
```

То есть взять элементы "key-value" 1-3-5-7-9 и т.д. до конца коллекции через Linq.

Comment: Используйте [перегрузку Where с индексом](https://docs.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__)

Answer (score 3):

Как и советует @Андрей NOP используйте вариант `Where` с индексом:

```
var numbers = new[] { 42, 3, 1, 5, 10, 76 };
var result = numbers.Where((val, i) => i % 2 == 0);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Со словарём тоже самое:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>()
{
    {"Photoshop", 230.0},
    {"Windows 10", 144.5},
    {"MS Office", 120.0},
};
var filtered = dict.Where((val, index) => index % 2 == 0);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылки по теме:

- [оф. док](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__)
- https://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/base/level2/2_1.php